# can a JSON be deserialized into an existing object?

Tags: ios, swift

We have some classes that conform to the codable interface.

Now we have a requirement similar to deep copy, but we need to pass the value into an existing object.

For example:

```
class A: Codable{
    var a1: Int
    var a2: String
    ....aN: Codable
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a1
        case a2
        case a3
        ...
        case aN
    }
}
let a = A()
```

We get a new JSON, and we can easily convert it into A object through decode.

But now we don't want the a's memory address to change. We want its ARC to remain in its current state.

That is, when deserializing, we want to write the content directly to the object a.

We hope to be more automatic. We can traverse the processing according to allkeys. We don't have to write each one.

```
a[keyPath: \.a1] = newObj[keyPath: \.a1]
a[keyPath: \.a2] = newObj[keyPath: \.a2]
...
a[keyPath: \.aN] = newObj[keyPath: \.aN]

or

a.a1 = newObj.a1
a.a2 = newObj.a2
...
a.aN = newObj.aN
```

Comment: One option is to wrap A in another class and have a function that decodes the data and replace the A property. Not sure if that is a suitable solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Deserializing will always result in creating a new object. So, I guess, the most viable (if not the only) option is to manually compare all properties and update the existing object accordingly.

You can write helper methods in your existing classes for convenience. Probably, something like this:

```swift
import Foundation

class A: Codable {
  var a1: String
  init(a1: String) {
    self.a1 = a1
  }
}

extension A {
  func updateWith(_ another: A) {
    if a1 != another.a1 {
      a1 = another.a1
    }
  }
}

let a = A(a1: "a1")

let anotherString = "{\"a1\":\"new a1\"}"
if let anotherData = anotherString.data(using: .utf8),
   let another = try? JSONDecoder().decode(A.self, from: anotherData) {
  a.updateWith(another)
}

print(a.a1) // "new a1"
```